# Angular 4 Display JSON Data from HTTP Get Request

Tags: json, angular, rest, http

I have a simple Angular 4 application which is contacting a HTTP REST server and this server is simply returning a JSON payload and I would like to display this JSON payload as is in the browser. This is my makeRequest typescript function:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-http',
  templateUrl: './simple-http.component.html'
})
export class SimpleHttpComponent implements OnInit {
  data: string;
  loading: boolean;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  makeRequest(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.http.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
      this.data = res.json();
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

The call to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 returns me the following JSON:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

I now display this in my html component as:

```
<h2>Basic Request</h2>
<button type="button" (click)="makeRequest()">Make Request</button>
<div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
<pre>Data Obtained is: {{ data }}</pre>
```

But in the browser, I see this:

[image]

How do I make my JSON displayed as is?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [json pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe). In your template:

```
<pre>Data Obtained is: {{ data | json }}</pre>
```

Also you have to change the type of your `data` property to `any` instead of `string`.

Comment: This still does not display me the whole JSON!

Comment: I still get to see only this: Data Obtained is: {"id":1}

Comment: What if you do a console.log(this.data), does it contain the whole json you expect or just what gets displayed in the view?

Comment: Where do I put this console.log(this.data),? In my typescript file?

Comment: Yes, right after you do `this.data = res.json();`. Then you have to look at your browser's console window at runtime.

Comment: So the console.log(...) is actually logging to the browsers console and not to the NodeJS server console? I gave you an upvote for helping me out!

Comment: Yes, the typescript code you write in your component is transpiled to javascript and run in the browser. NodeJS is only used to build the app.

Answer (score 6):

You have two options:

- Use the built-in pipe JsonPipe (`this.data` should be of type `any`):

  `<pre>Data Obtained is: {{ data | json }}</pre>`
- Get the JSON string manually:

  `this.data = JSON.stringify(res.json()); //data is a string :)`

or

```
 `<pre>Data Obtained is: {{ JSON.stringify(data) }}</pre>`
```

You have to understand that any value in a template is shown via calling its `.toString()` method, so a basic object (something like `{key: value}`) just shows `[object Object]`

Comment: Data Obtained is: {"id":1}

Comment: Strangely I do not see the whole JSON message!

Comment: Have you got any clues?

Comment: It means that that's what you have, there is no reason to show only part of an object. Check with your browser developer tool the network label