# Return plain JSON when calling specific router URL

Tags: json, angular, response

I have an Angular application that shows different pages. I can navigate by (hamburger) menu or by calling the specific route (e.g. http://localhost/samplepage). Now I want to return plain JSON content when entering a specific route (e.g. http://localhost/myjson).

How can I manipulate the response so that it throws away all the Angular generated component code and instead return my plain JSON?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45838585/2358409

Comment: That's outside of Angular's remit. If there are routes that should show JSON instead of the Angular app, handle those outside the app.

Comment: Can't believe that this is not possible to modify the response output in Angular by code. I need to grab json content from localstorage and return it as json.

Comment: Its not possible, what u want is a server response, which angular cant affect as it is a frontend framework

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    const obj = {
      name: 'Torsten',
      age: 54
    }
    const thefile = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], { type: "application/json" }) ;
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(thefile);
    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use Angular as JSON provider, too, and tested your promising solution with Angular 16, now. Unfortunately, it first shows the default template response and then switches/forwards to the blob display. When using that in the HttpClient call of my angular App, I get an HTTP 404 error. Seems like, for my Angular app, I have to fall back to returning a JSON included in normal HTML and use interceptors to strip it out from the incoming response. Works at least for the aware Angular app. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Solution

You can use `json.stringify` to show only plain json. Therefore you will still need a component, unless you want to have some guard methods to handle it there.
Like:

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  getStringFromJson(): string {
     JSON.stringify(this.someService.method())
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
{{ getStringFromJson() }}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvamcm

### 2. Solution

Put a JSON file into your assets folder, which you edited before. Then use the `Router` service to redirect to this file in any time, but going to this file will cause, that you are not in the angular application anymore

Comment: Hi Ling Vu - thank you for your answer, but that is not the solution I'm looking for. This returns a complete html page with html tags, header and somewhere in the body the json string. But I want to have a response from type application/json and not text/html

Comment: Ah okay, then is might not be possible with this since angular is a SPA, but I think you can have a workaround using the assets and put a json file there.